# Accessing class in the default package from outside the jar

Tags: java, jar

I created a public class under default package and then I exported this class as jar file. I then created a new project and added the jar file from my directory as a library in my new project.

My problem is, why the class in the jar file cannot be accessed outside the default package ? As shown in the screen shot there is an error in my test.java class under test package when I try to access the class from the jar file.

Any solution to this problem?

Thank you

[image: Screen shot of my new project]

Comment: What's the error in test.java? Could you show us the import statements there?

Comment: You should always put your classes in appropriate packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access classes in the default package from a named package.

Prior to J2SE 1.4 you could import classes from the default package using a syntax like this:

> import Unfinished;

This is no longer allowed

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6975015

Comment: Thank you!..I finally resolved the problem. I just created a new package and placed my class file under the new package and then imported it as a jar file. Now I can access the class inside the jar from outside the package it belongs to.